# Dependency parser for spanish?

Tags: parsing, dependencies, sentiment-analysis

Somebody knows if there is any dependency parser for **spanish**? I need to analyze dependency relationships between opinion words. Some relations that I know exist are mod, pnmod, subj, s, obj, obj2.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look [mate-tools](http://code.google.com/p/mate-tools/downloads/list). It includes a dependency parser for Spanish. [Here](http://aclweb.org/anthology//W/W09/W09-1206.pdf) is a research paper where the parser was evaluated.